# Laravel - Pass variable from a function to another

Tags: php, laravel

Is this the correct way to pass the id from a function to another ?

```
return Redirect::to('uploads/show', $id);
```

or should I use

```
return Redirect::to('uploads/show')->with($id);
```

the function that I am trying to pass the id to

```
public function getShow($id)
{
  $entryid = $this->upload->findOrFail($id);

  $this->layout->content = View::make('uploads.show', compact('entryid'));
}
```

The error i get is

```
Missing argument 1 for UploadsController::getShow()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `Redirect` you should do:

```
return Redirect::to('uploads/show/'.$id);
```

to pass variable to controller though router

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it as correctly as possible you need to craft your URL properly. The previous answer which uses string concatenation isn't **wrong**, but a better way might be:

```
return Redirect::to(URL::to('uploads/show', [$id]));
```

You will find though that as you get more routes, and especially the first time you decide to rework your routing convention, that using named routes (or at least controller-based routing with `Route::controller`) will probably serve you better. In this case it's a similar situation:

```
// routes.php
Route::get('uploads/show/{id}', ['as' => showUpload', 'uses' => 'Controller@action']);

// redirect:
return Redirect::route('showUpload', [$id]);
```

Also notice how you can pass the params directly in here (rather than using `URL::to()`) as using a named route isn't a simple string route like above.

Similarly, if you were using controller-based routing:

```
// routes.php
Route::Controller('uploads', 'Controller'); // I don't use this, syntax is like this

// redirect:
return Redirect::action('Controller@getShow', [$id]); // again I don't use this, but it's similar
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for the time being, the above answer will do the job.